# How to check the size of intermediate and root certificate size

Tags: ssl-certificate

How to check the size of intermediate and root certificate ? Our SSL handshake seems to be costly because it is over 4.8 KB per handshake and there are multiple connections which happens during the day.

Is there a way we could optimize it by reducing the intermediate certs by using 1 instead of 2. Currently there are 2 intermediates. Any pointers would be helpful

[image: certificate chain]

Comment: That's not two intermediate certs, it's one intermediate and one root. All TLS standards allow(ed) the server to not send the root, which saves in this case 1338+2 bytes, although depending on your server -- which you didn't describe in any way -- the method(s) of doing so vary hugely or it may be impossible, and mostly are not programming or development (thus out of scope for SO). Do you get connections from (always) different clients or multiple connections from the same client(s) and if the latter are you supporting session resumption? That reduces data _and_ compute.

Comment: ... Or can you get an EC(DSA) cert instead of RSA? That shrinks your leaf cert several hundred bytes, and probably the intermediate as well, although it may prevent access by some ancient or really screwy client systems/devices/programs.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Connections are from different clients. TLS certificates are enabled at the aws application load balancer and requests from alb to server is http. 1. Is there an option at aws alb level to stop sending the root 2. Can we skip intermediate certificate altogether or is it not a good practice

Comment: (1) I don't use and don't know about ALB, but add it to the question and possibly someone who does might see it (2) whether you _can_ omit the intermediate again depends on the server; it is not allowed by the RFCs, and some clients will be unable to validate you and thus won't connect, but some -- including probably most browsers -- will at least sometimes be able to find or fetch the intermediate themselves and connect